# How do I print out Boss Tone Studio livesets?

Tags: guitar, software, guitar-effects, synthesizer

I am currently using BOSS Tone Studio for both the BOSS ME-80 guitar multi-effects pedal and the BOSS SY-300 guitar synthesizer pedal to evaluate and compare all the patches available at BOSS Tone Central. These patches are in groups called "livesets."

In order to compare the patches I would like to be able to print out all the settings for the patches of interest in each liveset so that I can determine the principles of making my own patches that I will use in performance.

I could do a screen print of each patch page but that's a *lot* of clicking to get all the data.

I could also export each liveset of patches into a *.TSL file which is in JSON format and then pretty-print it.  But that's gnarly, especially for the SY-300, which records multiple signal paths between each component.

Before I start writing some software, is there already-existing software to print out all the livesets in my copy of Tone Studio or the exported liveset TSL files in human-readable format?  Graphics would be nice, especially for the SY-300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted a Python script that prints out a liveset or a patch in a liveset to https://github.com/johnsrude/BossToneStudio

boss_tsl.py

Prints the settings of a liveset that has been exported to a TSL file.

Currently only livesets for the BOSS ME-80 are supported. The BOSS SY-300 livesets will be released when ready.

```
usage: boss_tsl.py [-h] [-L] filename [patch]

Print BOSS Tone Studio livesets. Requires Python 3.6+

positional arguments:
  filename          File name (*.tsl)
  patch             [Optional] Display only 1 patch which may have spaces in
                    the name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  -L, --patch_list  Display list of patches only
```

Answer (score 0):

If those livesets can be found [here](http://bosstonecentral.com) then all you need to do is highlight the text, right-click, print. Then you can either print it or save it as a PDF if you change your printer type.

Comment: From the OP: "I could do a screen print of each patch page but that's a lot of clicking to get all the data."  And no, they're not all found on the webpage, at least not in non-modified form.